# Function imported from file can't find a module - what's going on? (python)

Tags: python, opencv, import

As the title says, I'm encountering an issue where a function imported from a file (`myfun_fromfile`) doesn't seem to have access to other imported modules, e.g. `cv2`.

Solutions that work are 1) defining the function in the same script it's called in (`myfun_inline`) and 2) importing the module *inside* the function imported from file (`myfun_fromfile_containsimport`). I'd prefer to separate my function definitions and workflow, so 1 is not an ideal solution for me. And solution 2 seems... strange?

What's going on here? And how can I import a function from file and have it call modules successfully?

#### Example code

file **functions.py** that contains two functions, `myfun_fromfile` and `myfun_fromfile_containsimport`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def myfun_fromfile(path_to_image):
    img = cv2.imread(path_to_image, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    return img

def myfun_fromfile_containsimport(path_to_image):
    # the only difference is "import cv2"
    import cv2
    img = cv2.imread(path_to_image, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    return img
```

main script:

```
# import module cv2 and two functions from functions.py
import cv2
from functions import (myfun_fromfile, myfun_fromfile_containsimport)

# define an inline function
def myfun_inline(path_to_image):
    img = cv2.imread(path_to_image, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    return img

#
path_to_image = '../data/train/5fb9edb4-bb99-11e8-b2b9-ac1f6b6435d0_red.png'

# compare from-file and inline directly
img1 = myfun_fromfile(path_to_image) # this does not work, see error below
img1 = myfun_inline(path_to_image) # this works, solution 1
img2 = myfun_fromfile_containsimport(path_to_image) # this works, solution 2
```

Error message thrown by `myfun_fromfile`

```
img1 = myfun_fromfile(path_to_image)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[385], line 1
    img1 = myfun_fromfile(path_to_image)

  File ~/path/to/functions.py:10 in myfun_fromfile
    img = cv2.imread(path_to_image, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined
```

Comment: Functions store a reference to the module in which they were defined and search this module namespace for names, not the module namespace they were imported into. Usual solution: Add `import cv2` at the beginning of "functions.py".

Comment: Ah, thank you. I now see the answer is to include `import cv2` in functions.py, but not in the function definitions itself. I'll edit my question and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer from Michael Butscher's comment:

Include the module imports in the external file. So in this, add `import cv2` to the top of `function.py`, but not inside the function definitions.